# How many couchdb databases based on data origin?

Tags: couchdb

I'm writing a web application that will run on a cluster.   I plan to rely heavily on replication between database instances in the cluster and development databases.   Some of the data will be created by users of the site.  Other data will be pushed to the site by the administrators.  I call this data userdata and admindata.  Is it best practice to put these in separate databases?

If they are in separated dbs, then replication should be easier.  I can push all the data in the admindata database to the live site at the same time as code releases.

If they are in the same db, then I can write map/reduce that utilize both of them, but replication seems like it could be much harder.

Any opinions or best practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go either way. If you put the two kinds of data in the same database you can selectively replicate each kind using a filter.

See http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Filtered_Replication for details.